# SSRS running report on external server using URL in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have our internal testing server setup with SSRS and within our ASP.net application we call the URL to run the report in a web page.

This all works well internally but when connecting to our production server which is hosted externally it asks for login details to the server.

Can anyone explain how to run a report on an external server using the URL?

This is how I call the reports at the moment for our internal servers, the external servers however, require further login details:

```
    string ID = fldOrderID.Value;

    string formatted = "http://dev-sql/ReportServer?%2fReports%2fOrderDetails&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&OrderId=" + ID.ToString() + "&rs:Format=PDF";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('" + formatted + "');",true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about ASP, but in my .NET app I pass `ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Pass, Domain);`

Comment: @SonnyChilds The 'ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials' is saying it's readonly

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.  Do the login credentials you're providing have read/write access?  I'm not sure why you would need write access, so there's something weird going on there...

Comment: Are you sure its asking for Login details to the server and not the database (datasource)?.  Can you run the report in production by browsing to it?